# How to do a sql_query with a variable in C++?

Tags: c++, mysql, visual-studio

I'm trying to get different values from my database dynamically so i need to put a variable in my mysql_query.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <mysql.h>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

MYSQL* ConnexionSql()
{
    MYSQL* conn;
    conn = mysql_init(0);
    conn = mysql_real_connect(conn, "localhost", "root", "ADAI1819", "projetADAI", 3306, NULL, 0);
    return conn;
}

int NbCompo() //Without any variable this work perfectly
{
    MYSQL* conn = ConnexionSql();
    MYSQL_RES *res_set;
    MYSQL_ROW row;
    mysql_query(conn, "select NbCompo from Envoi");
    res_set = mysql_store_result(conn);
    row = mysql_fetch_row(res_set);
    string chaine = row[0];
    int result = std::stoi(chaine);
    return result;
}

int NbProduit(string x) //And here is my problem
{
    MYSQL* conn = ConnexionSql();
    MYSQL_RES *res_set;
    MYSQL_ROW row;

    x = "Select " + x + " from Envoi";
    mysql_query(conn, x.c_str());
    res_set = mysql_store_result(conn);
    row = mysql_fetch_row(res_set);
    string chaine = row[0];
    int result = std::stoi(chaine);
    return result;
}
```

It Build perfectly but when i run it i get this message "Exception thrown at 0x00007FFFF7C1BD66 (libmysql.dll) in ProjectADAI.exe: 0xC0000005: Access Violation while reading location 0x0000000000000010." (it's a translation i'm french excuse my english).

Comment: Not that it matters, but why are you passing `x.c_str()` instead of just `x` to `mysql_query()` ?

Comment: Because, @TimBiegeleisen mysql_query() is a C library function that knows absolutely nothing whatsoever about C++ classes like `std::string`.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I sort of suspected something like this.  So, do you have an answer here then?

Comment: An answer here, unfortunately, is not possible because the shown code fails to meet the requirements for a [mcve], as explained in stackoverflow.com's [help].

Comment: at a guess `mysql_real_connect` is returning null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mysql_real_connect` is probably returning null. You need to check whether the result is null then call `mysql_error` to discover the error code.